# how to get events from Facebook event discovery page

Tags: facebook, api, web-crawler

I am new to Facebook Graph API and crawling. I found out Facebook had an event discovery page which contains lots of events within or near a certain city.(https://www.facebook.com/events/discovery/) It is very helpful for me to collect all the events info. 
Is there any API I can use to get events list from this page? If API can't be used, is there any other way to crawl this? Thank you!

Comment: There is no API for this specific purpose, and scraping is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks, I will seek other ways to get events.